# How to understand Graph result in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have following scenario in my `performance testing` using `jmeter` tool.

```
Number of Thread users = 100 
Ramp-up period (seconds) = 100
Loop count = 10
```

Ramp-Up Period tells `JMeter` how long to delay before starting next user. For example, in my scenario I have `100 users` and a `100 second` Ramp-Up period, then the delay between starting users would be **1 second** (100 users /100 seconds)

In the HTTP Request Defaults control panel, enter the Website name under test (http://www.google.com)

Refer Image:

[image]

Refer Below **Graph result** Image for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Latest Sample:** This is the sample time in millisecond.It is the response time for the last requested URL in executing the test script. In your case, it is 430 ms, that means the response time for the last request sample is 430 ms.

The **Throughput**: is the number of requests per unit of time (seconds, minutes, hours) that are sent to your server during the test.

The **throughput** is the real load processed by your server during a run but it does not tell you anything about the performance of your server during this same run. This is the reason why you need both measures in order to get a **real idea** about your server’s performance during a run. The **response time** tells you how fast your server is handling a given load.

**Average**: This is the Average (Arithmetic mean μ = 1/n * Σi=1…n xi) Response time of your total samples.

**Median**: This the midpoint of a frequency distribution. In here, 431 ms is the median for 1000 samples.

**Min** and **Max** are the minimum and maximum response time.

**An important** thing to understand is that the mean value can be very **misleading** as it does not show you how close (or far) your values are from the average.For this purpose, we need the **Deviation** value since Average value can be the Same for different response time of the samples!!

**Deviation**:  The **standard deviation (σ)** measures the mean distance of the values to their average (μ).It gives you a good idea of the **dispersion or variability** of the measures to their mean value.

The following equation show how the **standard deviation (σ)** is calculated:

**σ = 1/n * √ Σi=1…n (xi-μ)2**

For Details, see [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html)!!

So, if the deviation value is low compared to the mean value, it will indicate you that your measures are not dispersed (or mostly close to the mean value) and that the mean value is significant.

Comment: I know the basic definitions of above field. Can you explain me with exact number of calculation of each field?

Comment: If you know the definitions then you can also calculate these results. I can't explain these values after seeing only the graph results. You can use these basic definitions to verify your results. Try to use other listeners like `View results in table` to see the specific sample results and do the calculations. Thank you!

Comment: Definition:- `Throughput` represents the ability of the server to handle heavy load. The higher the Throughput is, the better is the server performance.

Calculation of Throughput in above image as 579.173/minute (How to calculate this number?)

Now you understand my question?

Comment: Collect each of your 1000 individual samples results and do the calculation according to the definition. JMeter listeners do this calculation quite accurately so I don't feel to calculate this for a huge number of requests. I already gave the throughput definitions. Did you check? Throughput is calculated based on time. Suppose, you have run your test for 4 minutes (Test duration), in this time you were able to send 4000 requests. So throughput will be 1000/min. Check you test duration and number of samples.

Comment: And yes, don't forget to check other JMeter listeners for better understanding of your results. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This listener doesn't tell the full story, in order to get the required metrics values open `.jtl` results using [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

Going forward I would recommend using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), this way you will get statistics and errors  tables and some useful graphs like Response times Over Time, Active Threads Over Time, Bytes throughput Over Time, etc. Generating dashboards is as easy as:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/results.jtl -o /where/you/want/dashboard/to/be/generated
```

Another option is using 3rd party results analysis tools like [JAnalyzer](http://epireum.com/) or [BM.Sense](http://sense.blazemeter.com/)